# Eclipse DSL code assist is not working after generating

Tags: eclipse, ide, xtext, xtend

I am using Eclipse for DSL development but I have a problem with it. I am using Xtext and Xtend to develop my DSL. But everytime I generate the Xtext artifacts from my xtext file, code assist stops working for all xtend files.

So far I tried to change my Code Assist Java editor settings due to some google search.
A workaround is to delete the .settings folder for the project and import the whole project again. But In my opinion this is not an acceptable workaround.

Thanks for your help!

[This are my current settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsB8h.png)

[image]

Comment: xtend content assist is not java content assist which you show in your preferences

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I checked it and sometimes the content assist does not work for Xtext artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your customized scopeproviders/ proposalproviders to have custom content assist in your dsl.

[Xtext 2.9 scope provider](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36224089/1389597)

Comment: In my opinion it has nothing to do with scopeproviders ... Somtimes I can't use CTRL+Space for inserting the >><< terminals in Xtend classes (I am not withina a >><<-block).